# Differences In Explanations of Quadratic Functions/Forms

Tags: summation, vector-analysis, quadratics, quadratic-forms

My textbook explains quadratic functions as follows:

> **Quadratic functions** are functions $g: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ that have the form
>
> $$g(h_1, \dots h_n) = \sum_{i, j = 1}^n a_{ij} h_i h_j$$
>
> for an $n \times n$ matrix $[a_{ij}]$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Definitions) defines quadratic functions as follows:

> $$q(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n a_{ij} x_i x_j$$

I have some questions regarding these definitions:

1. There are two forms of summation notation used: $\sum_{i, j = 1}^n$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n$. Now, as I understand it, these are not necessarily equivalent notations, since, with $\sum_{i, j = 1}^n$, we always have $i= j$, whereas with $\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n$, we can have $i \not= j$, since one summation, say, $\sum_{j = 1}^n$, is summed over while the other, $\sum_{i = 1}^n$, is held constant at $i = c \in [1, n]$, and only incremented by one once the summation over all values of $j \in [1, n]$ is complete. It seems to me like both of these can't be correct, so what's going on here? Am I misunderstanding something? Since $[a_{ij}]$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, it seems to me like the double-summation $\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n$ is the one we would be looking for?
2. How do these above definitions of quadratic functions/forms relate to the commonly-known **quadratic function/equation** $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$?

I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: In $\;\sum_{i,j=1}^n\;$ we **do not** have always $\;i=j\;$ . We only are said that both running indexes begin at 1 and end at n.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ahh, ok, that makes sense. So it could be equivalent to the form $\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n$, but not necessarily? (And, in this case, it seems it would be?)

Comment: point Unless otherwise stated, and that'd be pretty weird imo, I'd say it is always the same.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok, thanks for the clarification on question 1.

Comment: Beware that there might be differences between the names "function" and "form". In this context, a "form" is a function with some additional properties (i.e., its matricial representation). Also, can you complete squares and perform a coordinate change on that parabola to check if all quadratic functions are quadratic forms?

Comment: @Marra Unfortunately, I have no idea how to go about such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *quadratic form* on a vector space should be thought of as a homogeneous quadratic function. Here homogeneous means that every monomial must have the same degree, and quadratic means that it must be degree 2. For example $f(x, y, z) = xy + 3yz - x^2$ is a homogeneous quadratic in three variables, but $g(x, y, z) = x^2 + y + y^2 - 7$ is not, because of the degree-1 term $y$, and the degree-0 term $-7$. Hopefully you can see how the definition given on the wikipedia page allows all functions like $f$, while not including ones like $g$.

As for your second question, the only quadratic forms in one variable are $f(x) = ax^2$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. So there is perhaps not so much relation to  quadratic polynomials in a single variable.

If you want a classic example of a quadratic form, the norm squared on a vector space is a quadratic form:

$$ f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \lvert (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \rvert^2 = x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "monomial" in this context? "In mathematics, a monomial is, roughly speaking, a polynomial which has only one term." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial To use your example, $f(x, y, z) = xy + 3yz - x^2$ has 3 terms.

Comment: The monomials in the function $g$ above are $x^2$, $y$, $y^2$, and $1$. (1 is considered a monomial since it is $x^0 y^0 z^0$)

Comment: But $g(x, y, z) = x^2 + y + y^2 - 7$ has four terms, which means it isn't a monomial, no?

Comment: The whole function is not a monomial, the whole function is a sum of monomials. $f$ is homogeneous since it is a sum of monomials which all have the same degree (degree 2).

Comment: Ahh, ok, I see what you meant. Thanks for the clarification.